# Error occurred when I try download data from s3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

It is full log

```
  File "/home/workspace/viv_data_handler/s3manager/s3_downloader.py", line 18, in download_file
    self.resource.meta.client.download_file(bucket, key, dest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 172, in download_file
    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 307, in download_file
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 73, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 233, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 255, in _main
    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py", line 353, in _submit
    **transfer_future.meta.call_args.extra_args
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 599, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 148, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 177, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 273, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 222, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719)
```

---

Hello I am developing a program using S3 and I have a problem

botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.SSLError error occurred when I try download data using boto3 from S3

It works when another server use the same code. and It works when use aws cli on the same server(boto3 failed server).

I don't know how to solve it.

please help me. thank you.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code that is leading to the error, as well as the full error message?

Comment: Post the exact full exception. If you google `exceptions.SSLError` , there are various condition that trigger the error.

Comment: Although I posted an answer below, there is not enough information in the question to provide a complete answer. Please demonstrate your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any boto3.Session.client or boto3.Session.resource object, you can pass the `verify=False` parameter to skip SSL certificate verification. For example, when you create the client or resource, do this:

```
import boto3

boto3_session = boto3.Session(profile_name=some_profile_you_configured)

s3_resource = boto3_session.resource(service_name='s3', verify=False)
s3_client = boto3_session.client(service_name='s3', verify=False)

[insert your code here using the s3_resource or s3_client objects]
```

The [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) is your best friend here.